# Relative Motion and Motion on ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

When I walk on the ground I know that it's me who is walking and not that I am just moving my legs forward and backward and the ground is moving.But according to relative motion I should not be able to deduce that it's me who is moving and not the ground.
So how this can be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you were to perform two actions:

1. You close your eyes and walk over flat ground.
2. You close your eyes and walk on a treadmill.

You would find that you were able to distinguish that in the first case you were propelling your body forward and in the second you were propelling the surface of the treadmill backwards. The reason is that your body is equipped with a mechanism in your inner ears which gives you a sense of acceleration, which is an absolute phenomenon, rather than motion which is relative to one's frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

That you are moving is a concept based on your experience, human perception. From an objective and physical point of view it is indeed impossible to distinguish between the two cases, you can choose a reference frame for either one. But the natural reference frame (for a naive human) is the one where your surroundings are at rest, because the actions that your brain dictates for your legs have no effect on the surroundings.

The "I know that" part of your question seems to be central, and the question is maybe less suited to a discussion on physics, but to philosophy, psychology, ...?

Answer (score 0):

> When I walk on the ground I know that it's me who is walking and not that I am just moving my legs forward and backward and the ground is moving

Not only do you not know this, it isn’t even a well formed statement that can be known. It is in the famous “not even wrong” category.

Whenever you are talking about motion you must state the reference frame. If you are walking then you are moving at about 3 mph in a frame fixed to the surface of the earth. You are stationary in your frame. You are moving at about 1000 mph in an inertial frame fixed to the center of the earth (assuming you are near the equator). You are moving at about 100000 kph in a frame fixed to the sun. You are moving at 600 kps in a frame where the CMB is isotropic.

So whether or not you are moving depends on the frame as does how fast you are moving. Thus simply stating “I am moving” is simply an incomplete statement.